# Issues running basic Vowpal Wabbit

Tags: reinforcement-learning, vowpalwabbit

I am new to Vowpal Wabbit. I already build a base Multi-Arm Bandit model but I want to try using the VW Contextual Bandit, but am having issues with the command line arguments.

I am a little confused on the input for the train.txt, even after reading the documentation and tutorials. Right now, I am just trying to run a basic 3 arm bandit and my input data looks like:

[train.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTZwW.png)

My code is:

`!vw -d train.txt --cb 3`

but I am getting a lot of invalid actions. Not sure what I am doing wrong since this is same format from tutorial.

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfnKS.png)

Sorry but I can't embed pictures yet so the images are linked. Thanks!

Comment: Just for future reference it is always better to provide input and output as text rather than images so that they don't need to be retyped out to test.

Answer (score 1):

Actions in CB are 1 indexed. All of your actions should be in the range [1,3], not [0,2] as they are now.

Comment: But can you explain this then:

```
| a:1 b:0.5
0:0.1:0.75 | a:0.5 b:1 c:2
 
shared | s_1 s_2
0:1.0:0.5 | a:1 b:1 c:1
| a:0.5 b:2 c:1
```
I am a little confused on what the train data of a contextual bandit with adf is supposed to look like. The documentation says the same but I am still confused.

Comment: That new example uses ADF examples. I've answered this in your new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66996884/confusion-with-vowpal-wabbit-contextual-bandit-training-data-formatting