# Confusion with Vowpal Wabbit Contextual Bandit training data formatting

Tags: reinforcement-learning, vowpalwabbit

I am new to Vowpal Wabbit and am working on a multi-arm bandit model to recommend different CTAs for sign up pop ups. I already completed the walkthrough on the main site but am a bit confuse on what the training data is supposed to look like for the `--cb_explore_adf` version. So far, for regular versions (with set action totals) the data looks like:

```
action:cost:probability | features
```

which makes sense, but then when you get to the adf version, it becomes:

```
| a:1 b:0.5
0:0.1:0.75 | a:0.5 b:1 c:2
 
shared | s_1 s_2
0:1.0:0.5 | a:1 b:1 c:1
| a:0.5 b:2 c:1
```

I've read the documentation numerous times and I still don't understand how this works.

I think an example of data similar to mine of how it would be adapted to the above version would be great.

Example of my use case:
2 actions: 1 and 2
3 features: language, country, favorite sport

Some of the docs that I've looked at:

1. https://vowpalwabbit.org/tutorials/cb_simulation.html

[EDIT]:

Playing around with it, I created a train.txt with this input:

```
shared |user language=en nation=CAN
|action arm=10-OC-ValueProp10 
0:0:0.5 |action arm=11-OC-ValueProp11 

shared |user language=it nation=ITA
|action arm=10-OC-ValueProp10 
0:0:0.5 |action arm=11-OC-ValueProp11 

shared |user language=it nation=ITA
0:0:0.5 |action arm=10-OC-ValueProp10 
|action arm=11-OC-ValueProp11 

shared |user language=it nation=ITA
0:0:0.5 |action arm=10-OC-ValueProp10 
|action arm=11-OC-ValueProp11
```

But when I run this:

```
vw = pyvw.vw("-d full_data.txt --cb_explore_adf -q ua --quiet --epsilon 0.2")
vw.predict("|user language=en nation=USA")
```

I get a [1.0] which doesn't make sense. I am sure that I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

ADF stands for action dependent features. So each event/example consists of multiple lines, with the first line being an optional set of shared features (marked with `shared`).

Apart from the shared line, each line corresponds with an action.

So, when you provide VW with the input:

```
|user language=en nation=USA
```

You are asking for a prediction for only 1 action (since there is no shared line), which is why you are getting back a PMF (probability mass function, or the probability to choose each distinct item) which is simply [1.0]. This states the single action should be chosen with a probability of 1.0. However, reading the features it looks as though you are actually passing what should e the shared features.

For each prediction you need to provide all of the features for each action, as essentially the action itself is defined *as* the set of its features (ADF).

Your predict data should look something like (notice the label is omitted):

```
shared |user language=it nation=ITA
|action arm=10-OC-ValueProp10 
|action arm=11-OC-ValueProp11
```

VW will then emit something that looks like [0.9, 0.1]. You should then sample from this PMF (to allow for exploration) to determine which is the chosen action.

## Training data

The format of the training data is a bit confusing since the same format was reused from non-adf. The `action` portion of the label is actually unused since the *label must be on the line as the action it is for.*

```
shared |user language=en nation=CAN
|action arm=10-OC-ValueProp10 
0:0:0.5 |action arm=11-OC-ValueProp11
```

In the above example it says that action two here had a cost of 0, and when it was picked the probability of choosing it was 0.5 (the value in the PMF)

Comment: Hello thanks for your helpful feedback. To give a bit more context, we have two actions (shown above), and the cost is either -1 (click) or 0 (no click). The probability for both actions is 0.5 since the previous bandit was just selecting them with 50% probability. Sorry but I didn't understand what you mean by `The format of the training data is a bit confusing since the same format was reused from non-adf.`

Comment: Also, the reason I am using `adf` is because I was reading that it is best for actions that change over time. Since we will be constantly adding and removing them, I assumed this was the preferred choice.

Comment: I just meant that for adf the first segment of the triplet is not used because the action is the line it is attached to. ADF sounds like a reasonable choice for your scenario